# How do I view archived certificates? (eg makecert/certmgr.msc certificates)

Tags: windows, certificate

When certificates expire, they disappear but are actually kept in an archive. How do I find the these archived certificates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For local user certificates, run `certmgr.msc` and choose view>options, show "archived certificates".

For local machine certificates

- run `mmc`, Add snapin, Certificates, Computer.
- Right click "Certificates (Local Computer)" and choose "New Window From Here".

Now that the window root is "Certificates (Local Computer)" and not "Console Root", it will only now show view>options as a choice in the menu. Choose it, show "archived certificates".